# Jasmine and spy method

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

```
angular.module('mine', []).factory('MyFactory', ['$http', '$q', function
    MyFactory($http, $q) {
        return {
            getData: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer(),
                    url = "http://...";
                $http.jsonp(url)
                    .then(
                        function(response) {
                            deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            return $q.reject('Error retrieving data');
                        }
                    );
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    }
]);

function MyController(MyFactory) {
    var self = this;
    self.getData = function() {
        MyFactory.getData().then(
            function(result) {
                self.contacts = result;
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Error retrieving data: ', error);
            }
        );
    };
}
```

I am trying to unit test if data from factory go correctly to controller. Here is my unit testing code using Jasmine:

```
describe('component', () => {
  let $componentController,contactsList,ctrl,$q,$rootScope;      

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mine'));    


  beforeEach(inject((_$componentController_,_MyFactory_, _$q_, _$rootScope_) => {
    $componentController = _$componentController_;

    ctrl = $componentController('myComponent',null);
    $q = _$q_;
    contactsList = _MyFactory_; 
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;    
  }));


it('should ... ', function() {    
       spyOn(contactsList, "getData").and.returnValue(
          $q.when({
            message: 'awesome message'
          }));

     ctrl.getData();
     $rootScope.$apply();
     expect(ctrl.contacts.message).toBe('awesome message');
    });  
});
```

However, I am doing something wrong and I am getting the error: I am getting the following error:  `Possibly unhandled rejection: Error retrieving data thrown`.I guess the problem lies on spy method. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: one of millon examples of jasmine with $q and angular http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/

Comment: You're spying on getData **after** you construct the controller, which calls self.getData() when it is being constructed. You should call self.getData() in $onInit().